# SELECT additional table data

Tags: php, mysqli

I have successfully managed to select and return teams with the associated members. Within the members table there are columns like: `score_1, score_2` etc...

I am struggling to get those integer values out of the tablea to sit alongside the data:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT t.team_name as team_name, GROUP_CONCAT(m.firstName, ' ', m.lastName) as team_members 
FROM members AS m
JOIN team_members AS tm
ON tm.member_id = m.member_id 
JOIN teams as t
on t.team_id = tm.team_id
WHERE t.dashboard_id = $dashboard_id AND t.team_id = $teamSelect
GROUP BY t.team_name"; 
if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    // die(printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error));
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<h2>Team Scores: <span class="teamNameTable">' . $row["team_name"] . '</span></h2><br>';
    $names = explode(',', $row['team_members']);
    echo '<div class="tableHeader">';
    echo '<div class="col">Name</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">SDO</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">DCTO</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">ED</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">CA</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">DHPT</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">IRT</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">GL</div>';
    echo '<div class="col">IL</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo '<div class="teamNameMember">' . $name  . '</div>';
    }   
    echo '<br>';  
} 
?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
foreach($names as $name) {
echo '<div class="teamNameMember">' . $name  . '</div>';
}   
echo '<br>';  
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add `m.score_1` [etc] to the `select`?

Comment: @SteveSmith Where abouts should I be putting that?

Comment: Change the first line to `$sql = "SELECT t.team_name as team_name, m.score_1, m.score_2, GROUP_CONCAT(m.firstName, ' ', m.lastName) as team_members `

Comment: So that will output the score for 1 member, I need that to output for all members, ill show you in my question how im outputting each member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add those columns to your select statement...

```
$sql = "SELECT t.team_name as team_name, GROUP_CONCAT(m.firstName, ' ', m.lastName) as team_members, m.score_1, m.score_2 
FROM members AS m
JOIN team_members AS tm
ON tm.member_id = m.member_id 
JOIN teams as t
on t.team_id = tm.team_id
WHERE t.dashboard_id = $dashboard_id AND t.team_id = $teamSelect
GROUP BY t.team_name";
```

Comment: Im not sure how I output the score now though?